# Send ALL messages to one log file, and RavenDB logs to a different log file

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

This sounds trivial, but I somehow cannot manage to do it.  I have the below `NLog.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" throwExceptions="true">
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/App_Data/logs"/>
    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
            <target xsi:type="File" name="f1" fileName="${logDirectory}\log1.txt" layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${message} (File 1)"/>
        </target>

        <target xsi:type="File" name="fileGeneral" fileName="${logDirectory}\log_${shortdate}.txt" >
            <layout xsi:type="Log4JXmlEventLayout"/>
        </target>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="fileRaven" fileName="${logDirectory}\raven_${shortdate}.txt" >
            <layout xsi:type="Log4JXmlEventLayout"/>
        </target>



    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="Raven.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="fileRaven"></logger>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="fileGeneral"></logger>

    </rules>
</nlog>
```

This is ending up with Raven + ALL logs to 'log_[date].txt', and another copy of just RavenDB logs in 'raven_[date].txt'.  How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<logger name="Raven.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="fileRaven" final="true"></logger>
```

Where `final="true"` means that no more rules for `Raven.*` will be executed will do what you are asking (if I understood you correctly).

Comment: As long as the Raven.* logger appears above the * logger, it should make no difference

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

The reason is that the loggers are evaluated from top to bottom, the first one matching will be used, and does below will not be evaluated.

In you case this means that when logging anything Raven related the first logger will be used and stops the flow.

Comment: Yes it is possible, as per answer.  Seeing it now, it makes sense because I might want to log Raven queries to file, and everything to trace including Raven.  This way, both are possible.